# Load csv file into MySQL C++

Tags: c++, mysql, csv

I'm trying to insert data in a `.txt` file into  MySQL.

Following is the code, I tried so far

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>


#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#define HOST "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASS "admin"
#define DB "test_index"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    const string url = HOST;
    const string user = USER;
    const string pass = PASS;
    const string database = DB;

    sql::Driver *driver = NULL; 
    sql::Connection *con = NULL;
    //sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res = NULL;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "admin");
    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("test_index");

    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt = NULL;
    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\test_index\data.txt' INTO TABLE dataload_file_raw fields terminated by '\t'");
    bool ret = prep_stmt->execute();
    cout << "The data is inserted" << ret << endl;
    delete res;
    delete prep_stmt;

    con->close();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is failing when it is trying to execute `prep_stmt->execute()`. Is there any extra configuration I need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to escape the backslashes in your SQL string.

So instead of 
`"LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL..."`
You should have
`"LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL..."`

Otherwise the C++ compiler will be turning your the '\P' (at the start of ProgramData) into something and '\M' (at the start of MySQL) into something else, which means it'll be trying to hit the wrong path and probably failing because of that.  Every backslash in your string will need to be escaped.

You may also want to look into setting up try/catch for the MySQL error reporting, then it'll tell you straightforwardly what went wrong.